# How do I beat Dynal to get the idol component

Tags: fossil-fighters

I'm having trouble and need help defeating Dynal. 
My best vivosaurs are T-Rex, Guan, and Perso.

How do I beat him?

Answer (score 1):

"try to max out all of your key players, then if that does not work try to go back and get all 100 fossil heads revived to get Duna, Raptin and Dinomation a horribly strong team"-http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/960571-fossil-fighters/answers/103093-how-do-i-beat-king-dynal-to-get-dynal-raptin-amd-duna
I don't have knowledge about this game, but I found a question similar to yours. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Train your Vivosaurs to rank 12, and revive all Vivosaur parts.